# Are Instant Noodles bad for people's health?

Tags: nutrition, cancer

I have often heard people saying that instant noodles are bad for our bodies, because they contain a wax coating and wax causes Cancer.

First: do noodles contain a wax coating?

Second: Is it true that wax causes Cancer?

Comment: I've usually heard they're bad because it's basically just a simple carbohydrate and salt. Do you have a source for the wax or cancer claims?

Comment: Please add a reference to a notable claim.

Comment: Based on the title, I was thinking it'd be about malnutrition, or [burns](http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-504763_162-57337632-10391704/instant-noodle-cups-may-pose-serious-burn-risk-report/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instant noodles contain Palm Oil, not wax, to prevent sticking - but even if wax were used, it wouldn't really be a problem for us (in "normal" doses - everything can be unhealthy in high quantities; some candies are, in fact, coated with wax and nobody panics about those ;-) ).

snopes.com has [a very good article about this claim](http://www.snopes.com/food/warnings/noodles.asp).

Quote:

> [...] coating with wax [...] would be rather pointless, because heat will melt wax, thus incorporating what was supposed to be part of the package into the foodstuff.
>
> [...]
>
> Even if wax were used in the styrofoam containers, and even if some of it did get into the food, it wouldn't adversely affect the average person. (It might possibly cause a problem for infants or those with damaged or impaired digestive systems, but not ordinary, healthy adults.)  Though it's not generally known, a number of candies routinely contain wax products. (Rowntree's "Smarties" and Just Born's "Peeps" immediately come to mind: carnauba wax is used in these products, as it is in candy corn.)